# jQuery - if checkbox 1 & checkbox 2 aren't checked - change form action

Tags: jquery, checkbox

If neither checkboxes are checked, the form action should be 'not_checked.php' I can change the action if one or the other isn't checked, but not both. Is this a syntax error??
HTML:

```
<form id="emf-form" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="test3.php" name="emf-form">



<input type="checkbox" class="ahh" checked id="chg_db_url">
```

...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ahh" id="chgact">
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    if(!$('#chgact').is(':checked') && !$('#chg_db_url').is(':checked')) {
    $('#emf-form').attr('action', 'not_checked.php');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You're checking only initially the state of the checkboxes. Is that OK for you to ignore changes ?

Comment: you might want to use `change` event in the checkboxes

Comment: Do you mean if they are checked and the unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use the onchange event on both checkboxes:

```
$('#chgact,#chg_db_url').on('change', function () {
    if (!$('#chgact, #chg_db_url').is(':checked')) {
        $('#emf-form').attr('action', 'not_checked.php');
    } else $('#emf-form').attr('action', 'test3.php');
}).triggerHandler('change'); //maybe you would like to trigger the event too
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to check this once, not every time it is changed. In that case, make sure the DOM is ready. There are several ways to do this. Placing the code at the end of the page is the easiest one.

```
<form id="myform">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="checkbox1" />My first checkbox
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="checkbox2" />My second checkbox
    </p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () { // DOM is ready for sure
    if (!$('#cb1').is(':checked') && !$('#cb2').is(':checked')) {
        $('form').attr('action', 'not_checked.php');
    }
});
```

However, if you want to change it everytime the checkboxed change, try this code:

```
$(function () { // DOM is ready for sure
    $('#myform').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function () {
        if (!$('#cb1').is(':checked') && !$('#cb2').is(':checked')) {
            $('#myform').attr('action', 'not_checked.php');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('action', 'checked.php');
        }
    });
});
```

This will set the `action` attribute to 'checked.php' and 'not_checked.php' respectively.

Here's a live example which shows your form's action: http://jsfiddle.net/3znpG/1/

**Also, I would like to suggest to use one submit page and check if they're checked with PHP. This is more secure.**

Comment: just `input:checkbox` would do :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$('#chgact, #chg_db_url').change(function(){
    if(!$('#chgact, #chg_db_url').is(':checked')) {
        $('#emf-form').attr('action', 'not_checked.php');
    } else {
        $('#emf-form').attr('action', 'test3.php');
    }
});
```

[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/erawog/2/edit)

There's no need to check for both conditions separately, you can do this `$('#chgact, #chg_db_url').is(':checked')` and it'll evaluate to `true` if either one is checked, and false if both aren't...

Answer (score 1):

One more answer to the bag, how abt `.filter()`?

```
$('#chgact,#chg_db_url').on('change', function () {
    var len = $('#chgact,#chg_db_url').filter(":checked").length; //will get the length of the 
    if (len === 0) {
        alert("not checked");
    } else {
        alert("checked");
    }
});
```

OR, `not()`?

```
$('#chgact,#chg_db_url').on('change', function () {
    var len = $('#chgact,#chg_db_url').not(":checked").length; //will get the length of the 
    if (len === 0) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("not checked");
    }
});
```

Mightve mixed up the if and else loops, but u get the gist.